# Returning an abstract class from multiple inherited classes

Tags: java

I'm trying to do the following:

```
abstract class G {
    protected var = 0;
}

class G1 extends G {
    var = 1;
}

class G2 extends G {
    var = 2;
}

// This is where I'm having a problem
public G method() {
    switch(someVar) {
        case x:
            return new G1();
        case y:
            return new G2();
    }
 }
```

Java is complaining that method must return a type of G.  How should I go about returning G1 OR G2 (which both extend G)?  It very well may be that I'm approaching this entirely wrong...

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not related to inheritance; you must throw an exception or return something of type `G` in the case where your switch does not fall into `case x` or `case y`.

For example:

```
public G method() {
    switch(someVar) {
        case x:
            return new G1();
        case y:
            return new G2();
        default:
            // You can return null or a default instance of type G here as well.
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("cases other than x or y are not supported.");
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's like @Chrome but cases instead of instanceof.

Answer (score 0):

Add default option in your `switch-case` block:

```
        default: ....
```

Its complaining because if `someVar` is not `x` or `y` then it doesn't have any return statement.

**Alternatively**, you can add a default `return statement in the end`
e.g.

```
  public G method() {
    switch(someVar) {
       case x:
        return new G1();
       case y:
        return new G2();
     }
     return defaultValue; // return default
  }
```

Comment: bad idea the default clause should never be reached.

Comment: @RomanC : What do you mean? Even the accepted answer with several votes  has the same thing.

Comment: @RomanC  I am really missing something. If you are returning with switch case, it has to handle/return in all cases. How does compiler know, `someVar` is only `x` or `y`?

Comment: they are lazy to think so why they vote or I don't know who voted it was not seen on this site. Don't believe to what has been accepted.

Comment: only x or y better mapped to get instances of `known` types.

Comment: @RomanC We just tried to answer simple question, why compiler is complaining about `return` stating `all branches of the method should end up returning something.`

Comment: how do it knows if `someVar` is initialized or not?